# How do I :substitute() with the case sensitive flag in vim?

Tags: vim, case-sensitive, substitution

I want to use `:substitute(...)` in a case sensitive manner in vim, but fail to do so.

Here's the variable I want to operate on:

```
let s:Var = 'foo BAR baz'
```

I can of course *explicitely* set `noic` so that in the following lines `BAR` (of s:Var) is not substituted:

```
set noic
let s:S1 = substitute(s:Var, 'bar', '___', '')
" print    foo BAR baz
echo s:S1
```

Conversly, if `ic` is set, `BAR` will of course be substituted:

```
set ic 
let s:S2 = substitute(s:Var, 'bar', '___', '')
" print    foo ___ baz
echo s:S2
```

Now, I thought I can use the `I` flag for `:substitute` in order to make it case senstitive, but this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
let s:S3 = substitute(s:Var, 'bar', '___', 'I')
" print   foo ___ baz
" instead of the expected foo BAR baz
echo s:S3
```

The help for the `I` flag reads:

```
[I] Don't ignore case for the pattern.  The 'ignorecase' and 'smartcase'
    options are not used.
    {not in Vi}
```

My understanding of these lines is that with that flag, BAR should not be substituted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help message about `[I]` you quoted is **not** for `substitute()` **function**. it is for `:s` command.

The flag of **`substitute()` function** could have either `"g"` or `""`. if you want to do case sensitive match with this function, add `\C` in your pattern, like:

```
substitute(s:Var, '\Cbar', '___', '')
```

check this help text:

```
The result is a String, which is a copy of {expr}, in which
        the first match of {pat} is replaced with {sub}.
        When {flags} is "g", all matches of {pat} in {expr} are
        replaced.  Otherwise {flags} should be "".

        This works like the ":substitute" command (without any flags).
        But the matching with {pat} is always done like the 'magic'
        option is set and 'cpoptions' is empty (to make scripts
        portable).  'ignorecase' is still relevant, use |/\c| or |/\C|
        if you want to ignore or match case and ignore 'ignorecase'.
        'smartcase' is not used.  See |string-match| for how {pat} is
        used.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I *wrongly assumed* that the flags are transportable between `:s` and `:substitute()`.

Answer (score 2):

The help for the `substitute` command says:

> When {flags} is "g", all matches of {pat} in {expr} are replaced.  Otherwise {flags} should be "".

So the only valid values for `{flags}` in this instance are `"g"` or `""`.

However, using the `\C` flag directly in the search pattern may work.